# Why Uri can not handle www escape character?

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I'm trying to parse a url which has www escape character in its query part. The code is as follow

```cpp
int main()
{
  init_apartment();
  Uri uri{L"http://fake.com/path?key1=val1&#38;key2=val2"}; // A
  auto parsed = uri.QueryParsed();
  for(uint32_t idx = 0; idx<parsed.Size(); idx++)
  {
    auto ent = parsed.GetAt(idx);
    printf("%ws : %ws\n",ent.Name().data(),ent.Value().data());
  }
}
```

at A `&#38;` is escape character for &, it seems Uri can't handle with this situation. The expected output is

```
key1 : val1
key2 : val2
```

but the atcually output is

```
key1 : val1
 :
```

What should I do ? Should I pre-process the url myself before passing it to Uri ? Many thanks!

Comment: What I expected is both key1 and key2 will be parsed, but actually only key1 is parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the code:

- The URI is using [HTML character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML). Those are unrelated to [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) used in URIs.
- It assumes that the API automagically unescapes escape sequences.

Addressing the former is simple: Just replace the part that reads `&#38;` with `%26` to produce the following output:

```
key1 : val1&key2=val2
```

This is the correct (expected) result. The API will not (must not, even) unescape the URI during parsing. Otherwise it would be impossible to ever have a value containing a reserved character. Do note that `Value()` does return an unescaped string.

If you need to manually unescape the URI, use the [UnescapeComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.uri.unescapecomponent) static class member:

```cpp
int main()
{
    init_apartment();

    auto const unescaped{
        Uri::UnescapeComponent(L"http://fake.com/path?key1=val1%26key2=val2")
    };
    Uri uri{ unescaped };

    auto const parsed{ uri.QueryParsed() };
    for (auto const& arg : parsed) {
        wprintf(L"%s : %s\n", arg.Name().c_str(), arg.Value().c_str());
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
key1 : val1
key2 : val2
```